# Reading a file containing multiple lines of strings, integers and floats

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file containing a line containing a string, integer and float. The data is separated by commas and I've seen a tonne of information about how best to approach this. I've simplified by problem by first trying to read in one line, and then work on implementing multiple lines.

I've managed to read the first two pieces of data. It's the float that's giving me issues.

Here is an example of what it is I'm trying to read:

CHANNEL_1, 0, 0.453

```
char        CHANNEL_NAME_[BUF_SIZE];
uint32_t    val1_;
double      val2_;
    FILE *fp;
int c;

    fp = fopen("E:\\read_from_file\\config.cfg", "r");

if (fp < 1)
{
    printf("Failed to open file = %d\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

c = fscanf(fp, "%[^,], %u[^,], %lf", CHANNEL_NAME_, &val1_, &val2_);

printf("[%s] [%u] [%lf]\n", CHANNEL_NAME_, val1_, val2_);
printf("C = %d\n", c);
```

I'm able to print the string and integer correctly, however, it's the float that's giving me issues. It comes out as a random float, something like 34534524524523452345.0000000. I expect to see the float as per above, 0.453.

When I print C, which is the result of the fscanf, I get 2 which is incorrect as I'd expect to read 3, due to 3 data types being read in.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This shouldn't even *compile*, don't you get any errors for `fp < 1`?

Comment: It compiles fine. I will clean up the code later, namely making sure fp doesn't return NULL etc

Comment: Thanks, xing, that solved the issue. I'm curious, why did that solve it? I thought in order to ignore the comma I had to use a scanset?

Comment: I see, but then why does putting a comma on %u, work?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such specifier as `"%u[^,]"`. That format is treated as a separate `"%u"` followed by a separate `"[^,]"`.

The `%[` format only reads strings, it doesn't have any type-prefix (and it's not needed as `scanf` will stop reading integers at the first non-digit character in the input). Which means you can use only `"%u"` for the middle specifier:

```
c = fscanf(fp, " %[^,], %u, %lf", CHANNEL_NAME_, &val1_, &val2_);
```

Note that I added a leading space in the format string. That's because the `"%["` format does not skip leading spaces (like any possible newlines after the previous line).

---

With the format specifier `"%u[^,]"`, the function actually tries to match the exact sequence `"[^,]"` in the input, which it won't find, leading to the last value not being read. Hence the value of `c` being `2` (as `fscanf` only matched two values, the initial string and the first unsigned integer).

Comment: Or maybe something like (Assuming `BUF_SIZE = 256`), use `c = fscanf(fp, " %255[^,] , %" SCNu32 " , %lf", CHANNEL_NAME_, &val1_, &val2_);`, else `"%[^,]"` is too much like gets()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!